Can I write Bachelor / Master in Subject in my CV?
I recently posted this question in another SE forum, but it was closed. I was suggested to post this question here instead. I am currently fine-tuning my CV, and I am wondering whether I can wirte
Master in Subject / Bachelor in Subject

rather than
Master’s Degree in Subject / Bachelor’s Degree in Subject
Master’s in Subject / Bachelor’s in Subject

I am aware I could use the common abbreviations for Master and Bachelor (i.e., BA, BSc, MA, MSc, MPhil and so on); but where I am from, such distinctions do not exist and are thus meaningless. I am therefore actively trying to avoid them.
So, among the following options, what would you write?

Master’s / Bachelor’s in Subject
Master / Bachelor in Subject
Master’s Degree / Bachelor’s Degree in Subject

Also, regardless of whether you would write it this way, is it correct to simply say Bachelor in Subject and Master in Subject?

First: "Bachelor in Math" (just to use an example) is wrong. It's not proper English.  And, while this question may be closed for being opinion based, I don't think that part is.
Second: You say that the abbreviations aren't used where you are from, strongly implying that this is not an English speaking country. I'm pretty sure they are used in the US, UK, Australia, and Canada. But your CV should be written for the people you are sending it to. If you are sending this CV to schools or jobs in an English speaking country, I would use some abbreviation. If you are sending it to people in your country, I'd use whatever people there use (but, also, why is the CV in English)?
Third (and this is opinion): Of your three choices, i strongly prefer 3). Second choice is 1).

Thank you for your answer. I will use option (3), then. Is it correct to say Doctorate in Subject? Or this, like with Bachelor in Subject and Master in Subject, is also incorrect?

No. "Doctorate" is the equivalent of "Bachelor's Degree".  What would be wrong is "Doctor in subject".

Thank you for your comment. So I can use Doctorate in Subject, then?
